# Reading the HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA registry key using a C program

Tags: c, windows, winapi, registry

So I'm trying to obtain the system information by reading the system performance data, which is maintained internally by NT and copied to locations in the registry when a special registry key is opened. For some reason when I try to access the registry key it throws the following error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winreg.h>

int main() {
    HKEY hKey;
    DWORD dataType;
    BYTE* buffer = NULL;
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    LSTATUS lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA, "Global", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        if (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("Key not found.\n");
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else {
            printf("Error opening key. %02x \n", lResult);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Error opening key. 06
```

Referring to the windows [system error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), 0x6 corresponds to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. Where am I going wrong? As far as I know, I don't require any special permissions to read this registry key, so what could be the problem here? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA` isn't listed as a valid predefined key for [`RegOpenKeyExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexw) which would explain the `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` result if the documentation is accurate. To make sure there isn't something else hiding, you should call `RegOpenKeyExA` explicitly rather than delegating to the `RegOpenKeyEx` preprocessor macro.

Comment: @IInspectable tried using `RegOpenKeyExA` explicitly too, but it raises the same error. Also, it is listed in the [predefined keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/predefined-keys) right? These predefined handles apply to all three functions if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

MS states in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/using-the-registry-functions-to-consume-counter-data) :

> To obtain performance data from the local system, call the RegQueryValueEx function. Use HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA as the key. The first call opens the key. You do not need to explicitly open the key first.

I am not sure how to read their "You do not need to explicitly open the key first". You don't `need` to? Or you `shouldn't`? Or you `must not`?

I would just try to `RegQueryValueEx` as they suggest.